# Efficiently GET data chunks sent by res.write in browser

Tags: javascript, stream, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to *stream* a huge `Array` (~1GB) to the browser.

To do this efficiently I'm sending a chunked response via [Express](https://expressjs.com/) like so:

```
app.get('/chunked-response', (req, res) => {
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }].forEach(item => {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(item))
  })

  res.end()
})
```

How can I receive those chunks in my browser as-they-come?

For example I'd like to receive:

- `{ foo: 'bar' }`
- `{ foo: 'baz' }`

as separate events.

#### What I've tried

- Used [oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/), but it [suffers from memory leaks](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js/issues/68)
- Used [XMLHttpRequest.onProgress and a cursor](https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/5736866) to read the substring. However `XMLHttpRequest` accumulates the response on `response/responseText` therefore I eventually run out of memory again

**Note:**

- I'd really like to avoid questions on why I'm sending such a huge amount of data and focus on how to do this without running into memory issues.
- I can also get away with using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to send the elements back but I'd like to focus on doing this in a single request for simplicity's sake

Comment: I don't know much, but `req.on("data")` on browser side should receive every chunk separately. For each write call, one "data" event should come to request object, no?

Comment: There is no `req` on the browser

Comment: Hi. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @RomanRoman No.